# Send data from zoho crm to zoho creator form using webhook

Tags: webhooks, zoho

I want to get data from zoho crm to stateless form in zoho creator using webhook. How can i do that. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to take CRM record data, then open up a stateless Creator form and populate it with the data from the CRM record.

Here's how I have done it in the past:

1. Add custom link to CRM module
2. Link opens stateless form & passes CRM
   data in as parameters following this format:

   ```
   http://creator.zoho.com/{user name}/{application name}/#Form:{form name}?{field name}={default value}&{field name 2}={value 2}
   ```